# Bi variate normal distribution question

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$X \sim N(0,1)$ and $c>0$ such that  $ \begin{equation}
 \nonumber Y =\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    X  &  \quad  |X|<c \\
      &  \quad   \\
   -X &  \quad |X| \geq c
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}$

so $Y$ is normal distributed beacuse $P(Y\leq y) = P(X\leq y)+P(X > y)=
 \int_{-\infty}^{y}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du+\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du $

but I dont understand how can I continiue from here to show that $(X,Y)$ is not normal distributed

Answer (score 1):

To show not normaL: I suggest you work it out for all cases.  First case $P(X\le x,Y\le y)=0$ if $x\lt -c$ and $y\lt c$, since $Y=-X$.